# Sequence Generator for Context-free Grammar (CFG) in Prolog possibly using DCG

Tags: parsing, prolog, sequence, grammar, dcg

I want to write gen(G,S) in Prolog to generate a valid sequence S for a given grammar G, where G is of the format grammar([list of nonterminals], [list of terminals], [list of rules], [starting sequence]). The rules are in the format rule(nt,[x]) where x can be any list of nonterminals and/or terminals.

e.g. 
    gen(grammar([a,b], [t,q,y,z], [rule(a,[t]), rule(a,[z]), rule(b,[y]), rule(b,[a,q])], [a,b]), X).

Returns:
    X = [t,y]. 
    X = [t,t,q].
    X = [t,z,q].
    X = [z,y].
    X = [z,t,q].
    X = [z,z,q].

With all the info out there on CFG for Prolog (been trying for 2 days), I s/b able to figure out at least 1 way to do this, either using the built-in --> and phrase/2 or from scratch, but no luck. (Never posted on SO b4 & I'm a beginner, so my apologies if this Q is inappropriate.)

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried that you can show?

Comment: I can't seem to get 1 loc written. I've never been stumped like this b4. I can generate a sequence using --> and phrase/2 for a sample grammar, but nothing generic, so it doesn't help at all. :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to resort to special, non-logical predicates. This does the trick:

```
gen(grammar(_NTE, _TE, _Rules, []), []).

gen(grammar(NTE, TE, Rules, [H|T]), X) :-
    member(H, NTE),
    member(rule(H, Res), Rules),
    append(Res, T, NewT),
    gen(grammar(NTE, TE, Rules, NewT), X).

gen(grammar(NTE, TE, Rules, [H|T]), [H|X2]) :-
    member(H, TE),
    gen(grammar(NTE, TE, Rules, T), X2).
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that should at least point you to the right direction. It is different, because I have directly defined the terminals, non-terminals and rules as Prolog facts:

```
nt(a). nt(b).

t(t). t(q). t(y). t(z).

rule(a, [t]).
rule(a, [z]).
rule(b, [y]).
rule(b, [a,q]).
```

From here, you need a predicate that takes a starting sequence and applies the rules:

```
gen([], []).
gen([A|As], S) :-
    (   t(A)
    ->  S = [A|Ts]
    ;   nt(A)
    ->  rule(A, Bs),
        gen(Bs, Cs),
        append(Cs, Ts, S)
    ),
    gen(As, Ts).
```

If the symbol is a terminal, it belongs to the end sequence. If it is a non-terminal, you apply a rule to it, then apply `gen/2` to the result. I assume you know how recursion in Prolog works, the if-else, and what `append/3` does.

```
?- [gen].
% gen compiled 0.00 sec, 13 clauses
true.

?- gen([a,b], S).
S = [t, y] ;
S = [t, t, q] ;
S = [t, z, q] ;
S = [z, y] ;
S = [z, t, q] ;
S = [z, z, q].
```

To transform this into the predicate you are looking for, consider the following:

A list can be enumerated using `member/2`:

```
?- member(NT, [a,b]).
NT = a ;
NT = b.
```

You can add facts and rules to the database using `assertz/1`:

```
?- assertz(t(t)), assertz(t(q)). % etc
```

You could use `forall/2` to avoid writing an explicit loop:

```
?- forall(member(R, Rules), assertz(R)).
```

You could use `member/2` directly on the lists if you want.

I am sure there is another way too.

Comment: Usually using assert and assertz should be avoided.

Comment: @ChristianF I agree, but in this case it really depends how the predicate is going to be used. If you evaluate a different grammar every time, yes. If you only change the starting sequence, asserting is not _wrong_.